# Insert Numpy Array into Array with extending of the embedding array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

First of all, I work with byte array (>= 400x400x1000) bytes. 
I wrote a small function which can insert a multidimensional array (or a fraction of) into another one by indicating an offset. This works if the embedded array is smaller than the embedding array **(case A)**. Otherwise the embedded array is truncated **(case B)**.

**case A)** Inserting a 3x3 into a 5x5 matrix with offset 1,1 would look like this.

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

**case B)** If the offsets are exceeding the dimensions of the embedding matrix, the smaller array is truncated. E.g. a (-1,-1) offset would result in this.

```
[[ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

*case C)* Now, instead of truncating the embedded array, I want to extend the embedding array (by zeroes) if the embedded array is either bigger than the embedding array or the offsets enforce it (e.g. case B). Is there a smart way with numpy or scipy to solve this?

```
[[ 1.   1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.   1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.   1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Actually I work with 3D array, but for simplicity I wrote an example for 2D arrays. Current source:

```
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib

def addAtPos(mat_bigger, mat_smaller, xyz_coor):
    size_sm_x, size_sm_y = np.shape(mat_smaller)
    size_gr_x, size_gr_y = np.shape(mat_bigger)

    start_gr_x, start_gr_y = xyz_coor
    start_sm_x, start_sm_y = 0,0

    end_x, end_y = (start_gr_x + size_sm_x), (start_gr_y + size_sm_y)

    print(size_sm_x, size_sm_y)
    print(size_gr_x, size_gr_y)
    print(end_x, end_y)

    if start_gr_x < 0:
        start_sm_x = -start_gr_x
        start_gr_x = 0
    if start_gr_y < 0: 
        start_sm_y = -start_gr_y
        start_gr_y = 0

    if end_x > size_gr_x:
        size_sm_x = size_sm_x - (end_x - size_gr_x)
        end_x = size_gr_x
    if end_y > size_gr_y:
        size_sm_y = size_sm_y - (end_y - size_gr_y)
        end_y = size_gr_y

    # copy all or a chunk (if offset is small/big enough) of the smaller matrix into the bigger matrix
    mat_bigger[start_gr_x:end_x, start_gr_y:end_y] = mat_smaller[start_sm_x:size_sm_x, start_sm_y:size_sm_y]
    return mat_bigger


a_gr = np.zeros([5,5])
a_sm = np.ones([3,3])
a_res = addAtPos(a_gr, a_sm, [-2,1])
#print (a_gr)
print (a_res)
```

Comment: You could check out [`numpy.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) to pad with zeroes the bigger array before inserting the smaller one in that new padded array.

Comment: `np.pad` is complicated, and relatively slow.  I'd just make a new `mat_bigger` if it needs to grow.  Don't be afraid of a few `if` statements.  They are run only once.  (Look at the `np.pad` to see what some numpy functions do to handle multiple dimensions and parameters.  It isn't pretty.)

Comment: I solved it as you suggested. I thought, there is maybe a comfort function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is an easier way to do it.

For your first example of a 3x3 array embedded to a 5x5 one you can do it with something like:

```
A = np.array([[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]])
(N, M) = A.shape

B = np.zeros(shape=(N + 2, M + 2))
B[1:-1:, 1:-1] = A
```

By playing with slicing you can select a subset of A and insert it anywhere within a continuous subset of B.

Hope it helps! ;-)